# How to read 64-bit binary data using R and bit64?

Tags: r

How can I read a vector of 8 million 64-bit integers from a binary file?

My first thought was:

```
f <- file('foo.dat', 'rb')
readBin(f, "integer", size=8, n=8000000)
```

However this is truncating the numbers to 32-bit (with R 3.2.3 on a 64-bit platform.)

I assume that lack of 64-bit number support is a limitation of base R and that the solution is the `bit64` package. However I have not been able to find an example of using `bit64` with `readBin` to read 64-bit values from a binary file.

(I have found many related questions on StackOverflow and R mailing lists but always without a solution.)

EDIT:

The documentation for `readBin` seems to suggest that 64-bit numbers are supported natively but this does not seem to be true. The numbers are truncated to 32-bits. Test case:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> f <- file('/dev/urandom', 'rb')
> readBin(f, "integer", size=8, n=1)
[1] 1314660028
> .Machine$sizeof.long == 8
[1] TRUE
> .Machine$sizeof.longlong == 8
[1] TRUE
```

EDIT2:

Oops. I just read that dplyr does not support integer64. So even if I manage to read my 64-bit data I am not able to do what I want with it. Oh well. Have to look for a different solution.

Comment: From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readBin.html) `Integer read/writes of size 8 will be available if either C type long is of size 8 bytes or C type long long exists and is of size 8 bytes.`. Which *may* mean the problem is caused by the way the distribution was compiled. *If* that is the case, you may be able to user Revolution R's distribution. I don't have a file with 64-bit numbers to test this though

Comment: From the documentation's example, you could check the size of `long` on your machine with `.Machine$sizeof.long`, eg `if(.Machine$sizeof.long == 8 || .Machine$sizeof.longlong == 8)
    readBin(zz, integer(), 10,  size = 8)`

Comment: Good point. I also interpreted the documentation this way. However the actual behavior seems like a rude surprise? See EDIT in question.

Comment: You might be lucky using the `bit64` package: `require(bit64)`, then: `x<-readBin(f, "double", size=8, n=8000000);class(x)<-"integer64"`. You read your data as they were `double`s and then convert them to 64bit integers. You will need to check if the obtained values are what you expect (they might not).

Comment: Can you try with `numeric()` instead of `"integer"`? Modifying the documentation's example seems to be working with `numeric()` even though `integer()` seems to convert everything to 32-bit

Comment: Using `numeric()` gives me wild results like `[1] -5.435945e+222 -3.238310e+186  5.625128e+291  8.176722e-198`. I think it is interpreting the binary data as if it were a double which is not valid.

Comment: @LukeGorrie After reading them with `numeric`, set the class `integer64` as I posted earlier and see if you get your numbers.

Comment: On first glance this looks like it might work. Do you think it is really correct? I worry a little bit about edge cases e.g. values that decode as NaN and may be canonicalized, etc?